# Can a module install a theme?

Tags: 7, installation

Is it possible for a module to install a separate theme, or should I just ask to the users who install the module to also install a specific theme for a better experience?

Comment: The later, they are completely separate things or rather should be treated like that.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like a [Distribution](http://drupal.org/documentation/build/distributions)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a `MY_MODULE.install` file, add a `HOOK_update()` where you can call [theme_enable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_enable/7.x) and `variable_set()` to set it as the default theme.

Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Enable my_new_theme and set as default.
 */
function MY_MODULE_update_7001() {
  $themes_to_enable = ['my_new_theme'];
  theme_enable($themes_to_enable);

  // Set the theme as default.
  variable_set('theme_default', 'my_new_theme');
}
```

Comment: Probably rather `hook_install`.